# pass value to slot with QNetWorkAccessManager

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I'm trying to use QsignalMapper to pass my String to img_loaded function, on finished SIGNAL. But I can not get any result, please  help.

```
   QString mystring = "value";
   QNetworkAccessManager *m_netwManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
   QUrl url("http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/albums/80_9299765.jpg");
   QNetworkRequest request(url);
   connect(m_netwManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(img_loaded(QNetworkReply*)));

void MainWindow::img_loaded(QNetworkReply *rep){
   //Handle my String here
}
```

Comment: There is no `QSignalMapper` use in your code. Did you try anything? What is your exact problem?

Comment: Yes, I was experimenting with QSignalMapper. The problem is that I don't know how to use QSignalMapper. Could you please give some example for my case

Answer (score 5):

If you  want to supply additional parameters to identify networkReply try this:

```
void myClass::downloadMedia(QString url, int mediaType, int messageID)
{
    bool connect_result;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager2 = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect_result = connect(manager2, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(onMediaDownloaded(QNetworkReply*)));
    Q_ASSERT(connect_result);

    QNetworkReply* reply = manager2->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
// Here are the additional parameters
    reply->setProperty("mediaType", mediaType);
    reply->setProperty("messageID", messageID);
}
```

And there is the slot

```
void myClass::onMediaDownloaded(QNetworkReply *reply)
 {
     int mediaType = reply->property("mediaType").toInt();
     int messageID = reply->property("messageID").toInt();
     switch (mediaType) {
         // Handle different media types
         .....
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `QSignalMapper` in this case. `QSignalMapper` allows to specify additional data separately for each *sender*. However, you have only one sender (`QNetworkAccessManager` object). You could use `QNetworkReply`'s signals (as @derkode suggested) and use `QSignalMapper` on them, but this is an over-complication.

`QNetworkAccessManager` already sends `QNetworkReply*` object as a signal parameter. That is quite similar to `QSignalMapper` functionality. We only need to attach additional data to each reply. For example, you can create such private field in your class:

```
QHash<QNetworkReply*, QString> data_storage;
```

Replace `QString` with the type of your additional data (QVariant, int, or else). Add data when you make a request:

```
QNetworkReply* reply = m_netwManager->get(...);
data_storage[reply] = my_data;
```

Get that data when the request is finished and clean up:

```
void MainWindow::img_loaded(QNetworkReply *reply) {
  QString my_data = data_storage[reply];
  data_storage.remove(reply);
  //... read reply and use data
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try so:

```
QString mystring = "value";
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://images.gs-cdn.net/static/albums/80_9299765.jpg");

QNetworkAccessManager m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply *reply = m_networkManager->get(request);

connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(img_loaded()));


void MainWindow::img_loaded() {
   //For example
   QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
   QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: As I understant in this code we can give some property to reply, and get it after. Let's try